# Using Heroku Scheduler add-on with Golang app

Tags: heroku, go, scheduler

I can't figure out how to use the Heroku Scheduler add-on with Go.

I would like run a separate Go file periodically, but I can find the command to achieve that.

From Heroku's doc (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), if the app is not a Rails app, I should use a ruby script. But I don't know how to run a Go file from there.

Comment: Why not a worker dyno, or a background goroutine in your web worker? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Comment: I'm interested in the Scheduler because it spins off a new Dyno every time with different IP address etc.

Comment: iam having a similar issue. added a golang .exe but it wont run on the scheduler according to heroku tech support due to the servers being linux os.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up forking the same `main` function used by my web dyno:

```
func main () {
    if len(os.Args) >= 2 && os.Args[1] == "my_job_param" {
       // Execute job.
    } else {
       // Set up my web server with port, router, etc.
    }
}
```

Then, in the Scheduler add-on, I just call: `my-app-name "my_job_param"`. It's pretty hacky, but I wanted to find a solution using the Scheduler add-on.

Comment: That works, but I suggest using multiple `cmd/` directories instead. I posted an answer that explains that approach.

Answer (score 2):

The typical pattern is to do something like:

```
.
└── cmd
    ├── processX
    │   └── main.go
    └── web
        └── main.go
```

And you set [heroku.install](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-dependencies-via-govendor#build-configuration) to `["./cmd/..."]` and Heroku compiles and installs both commands into bin, so you get a `bin/web` and a `bin/processX` (`processX` is just a placeholder, whatever the name of the directory that contains a main package is the name of the resulting executable). In the above case your `Procfile` would say `web: web`, the first `web` being the process type, the second being the name of the executable. And the job you would tell scheduler to run would be `processX`.

That cleanly separates responsibilities

Comment: For those who are not using `govendor` or `glide`, this can also be set using an environment variable `GO_INSTALL_PACKAGE_SPEC`

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku scheduler will run any terminal command basically. So, if you compile your script into an executable called `myscript`, for example, you could simply put:

```
myscript
```

In the scheduler and it will execute that command, thereby running your script =) No ruby is required.

Comment: That works well with a bash script, but I wanted to run a go script and go commands don't seem to work on the Heroku server.

Comment: getting status 127. booo

Comment: .exe wont run on linux apparently